Looking for the source of a drasha
In the book “Between Cross and Crescent” the author cites a midrash which apparently says: “God revealed himself in four languages: Hebrew, Latin, Arabic and Aramaic”
apparently in reference to v'Zot haBerachah pasuk 2 but the author does not cite his source.

It's from Sifri Devarim 343:5 (on Devarim 32:2):

"דבר אחר כשנגלה הקדוש ברוך הוא ליתן תורה לישראל לא בלשון אחד אמר להם אלא בארבעה לשונות שנאמר ויאמר ה' מסיני בא זה לשון עברי וזרח משעיר למו זה לשון רומי הופיע מהר פארן זה לשון ערבי ואתה מרבבות קדש זה לשון ארמי."
"Variantly: When the L-rd appeared to give Torah to Israel, He did so not with one language, but with four, viz.: "And the L-rd came from Sinai" - this is Hebrew, "And shone upon them from Seir" - this is Latin (lit. the language of Rome), "[He] appeared from Mount Paran" - this is Arabic, "And approached from Ribeboth-kodesh" - this is Aramaic."


But the questioner is missing critical context. The context here is a midrash that G-d offered the Torah to several other nations, who declined it; then it was given to the Jews. Not that all these faiths' scriptures and beliefs are equally valid.

Reading "Seir" as Latin/Rome seems strange if the location is generally thought to be near Petra (or alternatively perhaps near Hebron).

@Shalom was your comment directed at me or at a different user's now-deleted comment?

@Henry midrashim are often intended to present deep ideas, and therefore often use a special kind of coded language. To understand the underlying idea of a midrashic text, you need to understand the meaning of each codeword. Oftentimes, all it takes is knowing similar uses of phrases in other Rabbinic texts. In this case, Seir refers to Rome because Seir = Esau, which in Rabbinic literature equals Rome.
